# phantomjs getting all img elements

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, dom-traversal

I have the following code in an exercise I've made for myself:

```
var imgs = page.evaluate(function() {
   return document.images;
});

for (var i in imgs){
    console.log("source: " + i.src);
}
```

but I only get multiple "undefined" messages.

When I try getAttribute('src'), I get:" 'undefined' is not a function... " error message.

I've verified the page has img elements with src attributes.

Solution:

I solved this by as suggested here by:

```
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
    if (imgs[i])
        console.log("source: " + imgs[i].src);
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-in-an-array-how-to-do-that-in-javascript) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    console.log("source: " + imgs[i].src);
}
```

instead

```
for (var i in imgs){
    console.log("source: " + i.src);
}
```

Comment: I get:

TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'imgs[i].src')

Is it possible I'm missing something more basic than this, and the code I wrote is fine?

Edit:

OK, I get two of those previous messages and then a message that the page failed to load properly.

Comment: @ReutSharabani you trying to iterate array as object so `i` will be indexes and not DOM elements

Comment: @ReutSharabani if my code give you errors you should first check your `imgs`. Maybe there some odds with images

Comment: This was eventually resolved by realizing there is a delay between some click event and the server update (updates every 5 minutes or so...)

It's working now.